# Why is my python script that runs the adb shell monkey command crashing for large values of events?

Tags: android, python, subprocess, adb

I have written a small python function that runs an adb shell monkey -p  -v  command along with an adb logcat command using subprocess.popen. For values larger than 100, this program crashes and I'm not sure why.

here is monkey_runner.py

```
import os, subprocess
def run_monkey_process(package, num_commands):
        monkeycmd = "adb shell monkey -p " + package + " -v " + num_commands
        monkeyprocess = subprocess.Popen(monkeycmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        logcatcmd = "adb logcat"
        logcatprocess = subprocess.Popen(logcatcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        monkeystring = monkeyprocess.communicate(input=None)[0]
        logcatstring = logcatprocess.communicate(input=None)[0]
        monkeyreturncode = monkeyprocess.poll()
        logcatreturncode = logcatprocess.poll()


        if(monkeyreturncode >=0):
                monkeyprocess.kill()
                logcatprocess.kill()

                return monkeystring, logcatstring

        else:
                print 'command failure'
                return 'you', 'fail'
```

I can put my gui code here too, but it's nothing special.

Here is the stacktrace

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\brandon.dalesandro\Desktop\Zonar\mankey\monkey_runner_gui.py", line 25, in goCallBack
    returned = run_monkey_process(package, num)
  File "C:\Users\brandon.dalesandro\Desktop\Zonar\mankey\monkey_runner.py", line 8, in run_monkey_process
    logcatstring = logcatprocess.communicate(input=None)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 798, in communicate
    stdout = _eintr_retry_call(self.stdout.read)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 478, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: What does "crashing" mean? Does it actually segfault and dump core? Or print out an exception traceback? Or return failure?

Comment: This isn't your problem here, but… you should never loop around `monkeyprocess.poll()`; that will have the same effect as just calling `monkeyprocess.wait()`, except to burn 100% CPU for no reason. (And while we're at it, never do `== None`, do `is None`, and putting extra parens around `if` and `while` conditions makes your code harder to read.)

Comment: Also, there is never a good reason to call `kill` after `terminate`. On POSIX, if `SIGTERM` didn't kill the process, `SIGKILL` isn't likely to help. On Windows, they both do the exact same thing. And calling `communicate` after kill is useless for the same reason it's useless after looping around `poll` or calling `wait`.

Comment: When I say crash, I mean it hangs until I kill it with task manager.

Comment: OK, a "hang" or "freeze" is a very different thing from a "crash", and you will get better answers if you use the right terminology instead of making people guess. Anyway, if you're just hanging, most likely it's inside the loop around `poll`, so my answer will fix it. (But it would be better to know _where_ it's hanging—which you can see just by running it in the bash/cmd shell, stopping it with control-C, and looking at the traceback from the `KeyboardInterrupt` that gets printed out.)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry about that. I definitely have much to learn, but I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* be your problem, but it's hard to tell without more information…

You've given the subprocess a pipe, but you don't read from it until after it's finished. The [warning](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) in the docs explains why this is bad:

> This will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use `communicate()` to avoid that.

It makes perfect sense that it would work for small numbers of commands—when there's not enough data to fill the pipe buffer—but hang for larger numbers.

Looping around `poll` instead of calling `wait` doesn't help anything; all it does is burn 100% CPU for no reason. You're still not reading from the pipe.

And calling `communicate` after the process has finished doesn't help either. If the pipe has filled up, the subprocess will be blocked forever, `poll` will never return a value, and you won't ever even get to `communicate`.

And since `communicate` already does its own `wait`, it's really all you need:

```
monkeyprocess = subprocess.Popen(monkeycmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
monkeystring = monkeyprocess.communicate(input=None)[0]
returncode = monkeyprocess.returncode
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I collect the adb info w/o filling up the pipe? Can I periodically add it to a string or a file and clear the pipe?

Comment: To avoid blocking the pipe, you need to loop around `proc.stdout.read(n)`, and make sure you don't do anything blocking (like spinning on `proc.poll()`) that prevents you from reading as fast as the data comes in). But if you just do it the easy way, by calling `communicate`, it already takes care of that for you. Which is why the docs suggest using `communicate` whenever possible instead of trying to do it yourself.